# Rails: Why am I getting "No route matches"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Snippet from routes.rb:

```
resources :templates do
  post :add_rates
  resources :rates
  delete :remove_rate
end
```

Now I try to use the "add_rates" path in my form.
Tried both:

```
<%= form_for(@template.template_id, :html => {:class=>"form-horizontal"},:url=> { :action=>:add_rates}) do |f| %>
```

and:

```
<%= form_tag(:template_add_rates) do %>
```

But I'm always getting:  No route matches {:action=>"add_rates", :controller=>"templates"}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Run `rake routes | grep add_rates` and see the correct path. You get: path | method | url | controller#action

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong:

```
form_for [@template, :add_rates], html: { class: "form-horizontal } do
```

or

```
form_for @template, url: template_add_rates_path(@template), html: {class: "form-horizontal" } do
```

The template, and its ID, and the action you want (add_rates) all have to be passed in as the same parameter. You can't give it the template ID as the first argument, and then try to tack additional URL parameters onto it. Additionally, in both cases, you're missing key parts of the URL. In the first one, you're just giving it an ID, and `:add_rates`; Rails can't take an arbitrary number and know that it's a *template* ID that you're giving it. In the second case, you're giving it `:template_add_rates`; how is Rails supposed to know *which* template you're trying to add rates to, without a template ID? You need to give it all three pieces of the route you're trying to match: `/templates/:template_id/add_rates`.

There are also a bunch of other weird issues/errors with the code you've posted:

- `@template.template_id` should be `@template.id`, unless you've explicitly deviated from Rails' conventions, which you should almost *never do*.
- Your routes are pretty weird. You shouldn't be adding a `add_rate` route, you should be using the routes provided by your nested `resources :rates` line.

  Your routes should look like this:

  ```
  resources :templates do
    resources :rates
  end
  ```

  This gives you routes like `POST /templates/:template_id/rates` for creating rates (instead of your `add_rate` route), and `DELETE /templates/:template_id/rates/:rate_id` for deleting rates (instead of your `remove_rate` route).

Comment: This answer is correct, but I hate this interface of form_for.

Comment: the array gets a symbol and an object. It should not be passing an array with multiple object classes, but in different parameters. Hopefully named parameters will help us with that.

Comment: Thanks meagar. Though I'm getting "undefined method `model_name' for Symbol:Class" when I use your solution: <%= form_for [@template, :add_rates], :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" } do %>